# Unable to find live file system error while running Ubuntu from USB

Tags: boot, ubuntu-12.04, liveusb, unetbootin

First of all there are existing Q&A on this issue on different forums (mainly on AskUbuntu). But none of those solutions worked for me hence I am asking in a new thread here in SU.

I earlier had a dual boot system with `Linux Mint 16` and `Windows 7 home premium 64 bit` (on my `Lenovo G570` machine). But few days back I wanted to use Ubuntu 12.04.03 instead due to LTS thing. My bad time started when I (like an ***) formatted the Linux partition using GParted live :(

Grub was lost hence I could not log-in to Windows. But after some hit and trial using `Ultimate Boot CD` I could luckily fix the Windows boot (MBR). I could log-in directly now to Win7 instead of `Grub Rescue` error. Now I created a live USB using Unetbootin (also tried with Rufus, etc. bootable usb creators) and Ubuntu 12.04.03 AMD64 iso.

When I tried booting from this USB Ubuntu logo came up and after some time it threw an error saying - `Unable to find live file system`.

I checked if `Virtual Technology/AHCI` is Enabled in BIOS. Yes it was. USB was plugged in 2.0 port.

Can anyone shed some light please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with *Unetbootin* is that it generally overwrites syslinux.cfg, making booting impossible. You can find [on the arch Linux USB Flash Installation man page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/USB_Flash_Installation_Media#Using_UNetbootin) a number of alternatives available to you. It is a very complete list.

Comment: Thanks let me try that. But I could boot Ubuntu using Unetbootin earlier on my laptop :/
BTW I lied :P I was trying to install Arch Linux and messed up everything :D and came back to MrEasyBuntu

Comment: @Saik0 LOL, Arch Linux rules. Use that page, the Arch wiki is nearly always perfect.

Comment: Yes the culprit was Ubuntu. It worked when the live USB was created using Rufus. I would recommend not to use Win32 Disk Imager as it will add extra headache of restoring the USB. Thanks :)